# Add external resources to jar in gradle from another project

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project that has a "resources" library (not java based). It simply contains a hierarchy of files that are used by multiple java projects

```
library
   files
   binaries
   etc
```

In one of my java projects, I want to include these files in the assembled jar file

```
// current definition of a sample project
project("java_project") {
 // dependencies omitted

 jar {
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }

    manifest {
        attributes("Main-Class": "mymainclass")
    }
  }
}

project("library") { 
  // is in settings.gradle 
}
```

How would I update the jar with the other project resources? I need them outside of the project because the same resources are shared by multiple projects.

Comment: Are the resource files only used within the same build? Do they need to be preprocessed, or do other projects include them as-is?

Comment: They are only used for this root project, but shared by subprojects. They don't need to be processed in any way, just added to some JARs during the assemble task for a couple java projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps someone will have a better solution but I added the following to the jar closure:

```
from { fileTree(dir: "library") }
```

I then can control the files with the exclude and include filters:

http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html